# Java - getter from a object attribute

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, abstract

I am working with these classes:

**class Klant**

```
public class Klant {

    private String naam;
    private String adres;
    private String geboortedatum;
    private double gewicht;
    private int bmi;

    private Abbonement abbonement;

    public Klant(String naam, String adres, String geboortedatum, double gewicht, int bmi, Abbonement abbonement){
        this.naam = naam;
        this.adres = adres;
        this.geboortedatum = geboortedatum;
        this.gewicht = gewicht;
        this.bmi = bmi;
        this.abbonement = abbonement;
    }

    public Abbonement getAbbonement() {
        return abbonement;
    }
}
```

**class Abbonement**

```
public abstract class Abbonement {

    private String begindatum;
    private int contractduur;
    private double maandprijs;

    Abbonement(String begindatum, int contractduur, double maandprijs){
        this.begindatum = begindatum;
        this.contractduur = contractduur;
        this.maandprijs = maandprijs;
    }
}
```

**class Milon**

```
public class Milon extends Abbonement{

    private int niveau;

    public Milon(String begindatum, int contractduur, double maandprijs, int niveau){
        super(begindatum, contractduur, maandprijs);
        if(niveau >= 1 && niveau <= 25) {
            this.niveau = niveau;
        } else {
            this.niveau = 1;
        }
    }

    public int getNiveau() {
        return niveau;
    }
}
```

Now I have a `Klant` object with a `Milon` subscription. At the moment I am stuck retrieving the niveau of their subscription.

First thought was:

```
piet.getAbbonement().getNiveau()
```

But it isn't working probably because it is from a abstract class I think?

Now my question is how can I return niveau from `Milon` if it's abbonement in a `Klant` object?

Comment: That is indeed not working because the getter is not defined in the abstract class. Is anything stopping you from defining a ``getNiveau`` method in the abstract ``Abbonement`` class?

Comment: Not at the moment, but the Niveau is class specific, the other ones don't have that attribute

Comment: @MrEmper If this is the case, you can't call `getNiveau()` without casting to `Milon` first.

Comment: And how can I cast to Milon?

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but using english variables would not only be a better practice, but would also make this issue a bit less of a headache to solve.

Comment: this casting should work: `((Milon)(piet.getAbbonement())).getNiveau()`

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! @Dropout I know, but I had to write this in Dutch, I am sorry. Thank you all for the reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is quite general, which seems to be the case, bring it to the base class.

```
public abstract class Abbonement {
    public int getNiveau() {
        return 0;
    }
    ...

public class Milon extends Abbonement{

    @Override
    public int getNiveau() {
        return niveau;
    }
}
```

Normally one would have a method in the base class, overridden in Milon to do something with `niveau` and possibly other fields. Say for displaying info on the Abbonement. Or something condensing the business logic `Abonnement.isGoedNiveau()`.

Casting Abbonement to Milon is more a pragmatic hack, and smells of bad style: at that place extra info is too concrete.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something similar to this:

```
Abbonement abbonement;
int niveau;

abbonement = myKlant.getAbbonement();

if (abbonement instanceof Milon) {
    Milon milon;
    milon = (Milon)abbonement;
    niveau = milon.getNiveau();
} else { 
    niveau = 0; 
}
```